# Can I update my OEM key for windows 8/10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1

When windows 10 was free to upgrade, I upgraded my Dell laptop that was originally running Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. A few months after the free upgrade, I had to do a factory reset causing my laptop to go back to 8.1. I was wondering if I put windows 10 on a USB and install it, would I be able to upgrade to windows 10 since it was already on windows 10 before?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a little bit of time devoted to searching will reveal that variations of this question have already been asked many times.

Comment: Just download the current Windows 10 ISO, install Windows 10, Windows 10 will automatically activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you did upgrade in time slot when it was free, you are ok to repeat upgrade again to Windows 10 again for free. You don't need to update any keys, it is already tracked by Microsoft that your windows 8 key is legal Windows 10 key. Don't panic after upgrade to Windows 10 if it is not activated immediately, I waited once 16 hours until its magic happened